# git over telnet

Tags: git, telnet

I know git supports SSH. But my 13-year old server does not support SSH. Only telnet is supported.

Is it possible to push to a git repository over telnet?

How to setup such environment?

Comment: what is the spec of your server? SSH can be supported by installing software, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't possible.

Even 13 years ago telnet wasn't an acceptable protocol to use, and ssh was already supported by any server worth using. That's even more the case now.

You *may* be able to set up support for doing git over http, including pushes. But you should really see about getting something that can support ssh.

Comment: Git supports arbitrary remote-helpers with ssh and https the only builtin ones. See eg. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote-ext .  The git-upload-pack command makes it really easy implementing one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the git ext:: protocol handler https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote-ext or set GIT_SSH to your remote shell and emulate the SSH options (to build the emulation script you can simply adapt e.g. [Execute remote commands from Debian to Windows via Telnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319804/execute-remote-commands-from-debian-to-windows-via-telnet))

See this post on how git communicates using git-upload-pack: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140089/what-commands-does-git-use-when-communicating-via-ssh