# How do I know the remote address of a Git repository?

Tags: windows, git, powershell, windows-7, telnet

I have created a bare repository at remote server (`192.168.2.122`). And have coded in a working repository in my own computer (`192.168.2.140`). I want to push my repository to the remote server but I don't know its address. The bare repository at the remote server is located at `D:\gtest`. So what is its url? `telnet://ilhan@password/D:\gtest.git`  ?

Also my working copy is at E:\gtest so the command would be:

$ `git remote add E:\gtest telnet://mars:password@192.168.2.122/D:\gtest.git` ?

Edit: If telnet protocol does not work on what protocol should I use except http, https, and ssh?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use telnet with git. See:

[git over telnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287934/git-over-telnet)

yo do what you want see:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

in your case, the easiest way, would be using samba to accesses the repository or git protocol. (since you don't want to use http or ssh).

Answer (score 1):

It seems both your *remote server* (192.168.2.122) and *your computer* (192.168.2.140) are Windows. If it is just for your testing on Git, the simplest way to setup git is to map a drive letter to your remote server 192.168.2.122.

Let's say you have mapped F: of *your computer* to the D:\gtest of *remote server*. You can simply add git remote by

```
git remote add RemoteServer /f/
```

then, you can push by

```
git push RemoteServer master
```

Answer (score 0):

*First you should clone the remote bare repository to host (192.168.2.140) using command:*
    git clone login_name@ip_address:/path (login and password should be your remote system which has bare repository and this does SSH)

*Once cloned you can code on your host system and then run the command:*
    git remote -v (you will be able to see the detailed information of remotes but before this either you need to clone from remote or you have add remote explicitly)

Answer (score 0):

That's easy,you just need to use the command:git remote -v.If you want to know more about this command,you can use the command: git remote --help.