# Execute remote commands from Debian to Windows via Telnet

Tags: windows, debian, telnet, expect

I am working on remotely executing a command line in Windows from Debian. For that, I tried to use the bash script below. Using the **expect** tool, it consists in connecting via **telnet** to the remote server, entering username and password values and sending the command line desired.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20
set name 192.168.1.46
set user Administrateur
set password MSapp/*2013
set cmd "TASKKILL /F /IM Tomcat6.exe"

spawn telnet 192.168.1.46
expect "login:"
send "$user\r"
expect "password:"
send "$password\r"
expect "C:\Users\Administrateur>"
send "$cmd\r"
```

The telnet connection is well established. But, the command line is not executed.

Could someone tell me what is wrong with my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add one more `expect` statement at the end, like as follows,

```
send "$cmd\r"
expect "C:\Users\Administrateur>"
```

Basically, `expect` will work with two feasible commands such as `send` and `expect`. If `send` is used, then it is mandatory to have `expect` (in most of the cases) afterwards. (while the vice-versa is not required to be mandatory)

This is because without that we will be missing out what is happening in the spawned process as `expect` will assume that you simply need to send one string value and not expecting anything else from the session.